# Calculated column: Value based on two date columns

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a list with two date columns:

1) Expiration Date

2) Today's Date

I'd like for the third column (Status) to produce this calculation:

1. Today's date is equals/greater than Expiration date =Expired;
2. when Today's Date < Expiration=Valid

Can someone write an if statement for this?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are using the "Today's Date" column somewhere else in your application, you could eliminate adding one extra field by using out of the box `Today()` function directly in the formula.

```
=IF(Today()>=[Expiration Date],"Expired","Valid")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below formula.

```
=IF([Today's Date]>=[Expiration Date],[Expiration Date],[Today's Date])
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps:

1. Go to the list settings.
2. Create new calculated field with name "Status".
3. Use below formula in formula section:

   `=IF([Today's Date]>=[Expiration Date],"Expired","Valid")`
4. Return data type from this formula as "Single line of text".

Comment: Have you tried this?